# Find the most repeated character out of 4 strings

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing

Let's say I have a document & the document is spread across 4 different machines, I would like to get a character which has the highest repeated count (all 4 machines combined).

One approach I have is to use a hashmap in each machine and calculate the frequency on each machine individually and then pass that hashmap to the main server where hashmaps from all the 4 machines will be merged.
Thus we'll get the character with the highest frequency.

But the cache here is that I want to minimize the data transferred from each machine.

What improvements can be made ?

**[EDIT]**
Each machine holds a part of the document

Comment: *" I would like to get a character which has the highest repeated count (all 4 machines combined)"*. That's not clear to me : how the count is different on *"all 4 machines combined"* than on just one if that's the same document ? What do I miss ? Do you mean that each machine only holds a part of the document ?

Comment: yes, each machine has a part of the document

Comment: I would not worry about data transfer. Lets say you make pairs character (2 bytes), frequency (4 bytes). If you transfer 100 most frequent chars (English alphabet has 26 letters + some special chars) the transfer will be (2+4)*100 = 600bytes

Comment: There will be some protocol/extra data, but I think when you will try to come up with some special protocol, your data transfer will be higher than with some "stupid" method

Comment: The only way to avoid the obvious solution would force you to sometimes makes new requests for more information. I doubt this would be worth the overhead.

Comment: @dystroy, can you please elaborate on requesting more information.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind it taking longer...

1. Each computer passes the most frequent character(s). Hopefully, the number of characters with the highest frequency is low. Ideally, it would be almost always only one.
2. Main server combines them into a set. If the set has a single character done. Otherwise this set is passed along to the computers, likely as an array or list. Assuming only one character from each computer, this list would have only 2-4 characters.
3. Each computer returns the frequencies of each character in the set.
4. Main server sums the frequencies, obtaining the most frequent.

Comment: This looks like the worst solution. In networking there are more costs related to requesting (latency mainly) than to a few bytes spared. Directly starting at 3 (that is, doing the obvious) would likely be more efficient.

Comment: The key is that the frequency data is not actually sent the first time. You still need the second request in order to ensure that the most frequent was not missed. The main thing though is that since the question is being asked, it seems to imply that person who asked the question may think that the few bytes are worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I assert that without prior knowledge of the distribution of characters in the document then any approach you take will have to reduce the data from all 4 computers onto one of them.  To minimise the data transferred it is necessary to minimise the size of the data structure which holds the character counts on each computer.

Supposing that you are working with an alphabet with `N` characters your problem is now the design of a data structure which can hold `N` integers (in some range `[0..m]`, `m` being the number of characters in the alphabet) and there is any number of such data structures to be found.

Of course, if you have prior knowledge of the distribution of characters, for example if you know that it is pure text written in English, you have a range of possible approaches to data compression.

Given the relatively small values for `N` and `m` likely to be found in practice I agree with the general thrust of the commentary, that it is probably not worth devising a complicated structure to minimise the amount of data transferred, sending an array of `N` integers would be adequate in most conceivable circumstances.